# Recursion: Finding number of elements

Tags: java, recursion

I have following recursive method that returns the number of element in a nested Collection. A Collection contains child Collections plus Elements.
Is there a faster algorithm to achieve this?

```
int elementCount = 0;
@Override
public int getElementCount(CollectionDTO collectionDTO){

    if(collectionDTO == null){

        return elementCount;

    }

    if (collectionDTO.getChildCollectionDTOs() != null
            && collectionDTO.getChildCollectionDTOs().size() > 0) {

        for (CollectionDTO collection : collectionDTO.getChildCollectionDTOs()) 

                getElementCount(collection);

    }


        if(collectionDTO.elements != null && collectionDTO.elements.size() > 0)
            elementCount +=collectionDTO.elements.size();

    return elementCount;
}
```

Comment: What is CollectionDTO ?

Comment: Did you tried to debug code or at least read it aloud to yourself? Are you asking for canonical version of such code or expecting someone to find bugs in your code?

Comment: I am sorry, my method is returning correct count. I was ignoring  a check. Yes, u can comment if there is any other better or faster way to get count?

Comment: You should declare `elementCount` inside the method and add to it the results of the recursive calls: `elementCount += getElementCount(collection);`. If you'll do that, you'll be able to declare this method as `static` (It's looks like a static method). Or, if you wrote `CollectionDTO` class, you should declare this method inside it, and use inside the method `this` instead of accepting the `CollectionDTO` as an argument. This won't make your code faster but this is a more proper way.

Comment: If you won't do my first suggestion, your code **won't work** after the first call because you're not reseting `elementCount`.

Comment: My method might not be efficient, but it is correct.

Comment: I think this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks for introducing to codereview.

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case you are calling `collectionDTO.getChildCollectionDTOs()` three times so you should consider to call it just once, store the result in a variable and reuse it.

If another caller of this method which has the same reference to this object comes into play the usage of that class level variable `elementCount` will have side effects and won't return the correct result.

You should always use braces `{}` although they are optional for single lined `if` statements or `for` loops. This will just make your code less error prone.

Applying these points will lead to

```
@Override
public int getElementCount(CollectionDTO collectionDTO){

    if(collectionDTO == null){

        return 0;
    }

    int elementCount = 0;

    if(collectionDTO.elements != null && collectionDTO.elements.size() > 0) {

        elementCount +=collectionDTO.elements.size();
    }

    List<CollectionDTO> children = collectionDTO.getChildCollectionDTOs();

    if (children == null){

        return elementCount;
    }

    for (CollectionDTO collection : children) 

         elementCount += getElementCount(collection);

    }

    return elementCount;
}
```